Android Credential Manager share passwords between apps
I have 2 apps. I want to share the credentials (username, password) between the 2 apps. Is that possible? I've created a relation like this and hosted it on GitHub pages. Both are debugged apps.
The link is https://.github.io/.well-known/assetlinks.json
[
    {
      "relation": [
        "delegate_permission/common.get_login_creds"
      ],
      "target": {
        "namespace": "android_app",
        "package_name": "com.practice.sharing1",
        "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
          "B0:99:5C:C8:07:12:8E:62:D6:99:D7:54:B2:FC:D8:AA:F4:A2:13:94:A8:38:22:D1:D3:40:59:5E:16:C3:69:8F"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "relation": [
        "delegate_permission/common.get_login_creds"
      ],
      "target": {
        "namespace": "android_app",
        "package_name": "com.practice.sharing2",
        "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
          "B0:99:5C:C8:07:12:8E:62:D6:99:D7:54:B2:FC:D8:AA:F4:A2:13:94:A8:38:22:D1:D3:40:59:5E:16:C3:69:8F"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]      

I've specified the assetlinks.json.
<string name="asset_statements" translatable="false">
    [{
      \"include\": \"https://<git-hub-name>.github.io/.well-known/assetlinks.json\"
    }]
    </string>

I've added it to the manifest file.
<meta-data android:name="asset_statements" android:resource="@string/asset_statements"/>

Adding the intent filter.
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
    <data android:host="<git-hub-name>.github.io" />
</intent-filter>

And the login method.
private val credentialManager = CredentialManager.create(activity)

suspend fun signIn(): SignInResult {
    return try {
        val credentialResponse = credentialManager.getCredential(
            context = activity,
            request = GetCredentialRequest(
                credentialOptions = listOf(GetPasswordOption())
            )
        )

        val credential = credentialResponse.credential as? PasswordCredential
            ?: return SignInResult.Failure

            // Make login API call here with credential.id and credential.password

        SignInResult.Success(credential.id)

    } catch(e: GetCredentialCancellationException) {
          e.printStackTrace()
          SignInResult.Cancelled
    } catch(e: NoCredentialException) {
          e.printStackTrace()
          SignInResult.NoCredentials
    } catch(e: GetCredentialException) {
          e.printStackTrace()
          SignInResult.Failure
    }
}

